# Creating a NPS report with data from Delighted.com?

Tags: lightning, reporting, survey

My company is using Delighted.com as one way of measuring customer engagement via a net promoter score(NPS). I've integrated Delighted.com with Salesforce and each survey response and score is found in the Contact Record using a related List.

I've made a "contacts with Accounts and Records" report and have the usual first name, last name, score, comment,timestamp and have the Account: Delighted NPS column added to the report, which i've chosen to Average.

Am I on the right path?? Any advice? My goal is to have the NPS report be on my team's dashboard for us to monitor and track the NPS score.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether we can tell you if you're on the right track because we don't know your goals or KPIs. Are you struggling with a specific problem, such as building a dashboard?

Comment: Not struggling to build a dashboard, that is created just fine. Struggling to create a report of net promoter score data from my clients that is synced to these same clients's contact records in Salesforce Lightning.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to add specifics about what you're expecting to happen and where you're stuck with the implementation?